# Setting the colorkey doesn't make that color transparent (Python/Pygame)

Tags: python, pygame

As said in the title, I am having trouble making one color transparent on a sprite that I have. I set the colorkey to white, but the white spaces on the sprite do not become transparent.

Here's what I have:

```
player_image = pygame.image.load("blanksprite.png").convert()
player_image.set_colorkey(white)
screen.blit(player_image, [x,y])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to Pygame, but does it work if you use [`Surface.convert_alpha`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha) instead of [`Surface.convert`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert)?

```
player_image = pygame.image.load("blanksprite.png").convert_alpha()
```

Comment: No, for some reason,  and unfortunately, that does not work. I saw elsewhere in another question to do that, but it didn't work.

Comment: Okay. I did it. I placed the 'player_image.set_colorkey(white)' in the wrong place. Now it's transparent.

Comment: That will enable the alpha channel, which is different than colorkey transparency.

Answer (score 0):

I placed 'player_image.set_colorkey(white)' in the wrong place, after the image was blitted at first, and before the main program. I moved it to right before the image was to be blitted and it became transparent.